# A noun for sexually repressed individuals imposing their views on others

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

I am looking for a pejorative (but not vulgar) noun describing individuals whom I allege are sexually repressed, moralizing, pontificating and who would use their authority to impose their view on others.

I don't think 'conservative' or 'traditionalist' really captures the strength of it but that is the kind of direction in which I am looking.

I am certain there is the perfect word but it seems to be out of my grasp. Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems to me *sexually repressed, moralizing, pontificating* are just three randomly-selected insulting terms. There's no particular reason why English should have one specific term covering all three attributes.

Comment: @FumbleFinger I assure you they are precisely selected terms in the context of the complaint I am writing in respect of some forthcoming legislation.

Comment: Hmm. I think what you're looking at here is a *stereotype* - but perhaps ***Victorian*** has the connotations you seek.

Comment: Any one  of the money-making  so-called *TV evangelists*? Wikipedia labels the money-spinning  sector [Televangelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Televangelism)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, *Victorian* is a historical signifier applicable to many who were not this way at all--Oscar Wilde, for instance. I would suggest *Puritan* and/or *prude.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider a term derived from the name *[Comstock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Comstock)*

> Anthony Comstock (March 7, 1844 – September 21, 1915) was a United States Postal Inspector and politician dedicated to ideas of Victorian morality. The terms "comstockery" and "Comstockism" were used for his extensive campaign to censor materials he considered indecent and obscene, such as birth control information.

*Wikipedia*

The adjective *[Comstockian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Comstockian)* is sometimes found. You could use it as a noun form to describe those subscribing to Mr. Comstock's approach to civil discourse and enforcement.

Comment: The etymology of this fits in perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Definition of bluenose
:  a person who advocates a rigorous moral code
bluenosed play \-ˌnōzd\ adjective
See words that rhyme with bluenose.           merriam-webster.com

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi Sounds like a good answer. I would vote for it.